# Creating windows forms open new form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When you create a new Windows Forms application, what's the easiest way from dropping a button on the page, creating a click event which will open a new form.

My method requires clicking a button which will open up 9 new forms, all together, but I want to be able to position them where I want, I know the code for this, I just can't seem to open up multiple new forms at the same time?

Button -> Click -> Open 9 new forms which must be open at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you would do this would depend on whether the forms are all the same or not but

```
For i as integer = 0 to 8

   dim frm as new Form1
   frm.Show

Next
```

Using the static method ie: form1.show is not generally a good idea.

Cheers

Comment: This didn't work after I applied similar in the Form1.cs after InitializeComponent(); I just got errors.

Comment: Nevermind, I changed it to var frm = new Form2(); and worked like a charm.

Comment: I didn't spot the c# tag and assumed this was a VB question for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Richard very generous of you to mark this as an answer after i got it in the wrong language. Ta

Comment: No problem and you really wasn't far off.

Answer (score 4):

To open a new form

```
MyForm myForm = new MyForm()
myForm.Show();
```

Where `MyForm` is a class that inherits from `Form` (i.e. your designed form)

Comment: MyForm initialisation of your code isn't working, it's highlighting as an invalid namespace.

Comment: @Richard You need to replace `MyForm` with your form - probably something like `Form1` unless you have renamed your forms.

Comment: I see, but I did need the structure within an array and I'm still learning, I'll give you +1, thanks.

Comment: @Richard Ah ok - I imagined that you have 9 different forms you wanted to open rather than wanting 9 instances of the same form displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in C# using `System.Windows.Forms`

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form myForm = new Form();
        myForm.Show();
    }
```

To open more than 1 form, a loop with each form would be required.

```
    foreach (Form form in formArray)
    {
        form.Show();
    }
```